# Different Types in Scala v. Java Reflection Example

Tags: java, scala

I defined an `object Foo`:

```
scala> object Foo { final def foo = "bar" }
defined object Foo
```

Then, using Reflection, I invoked `Foo#hashCode`. Note that the output's type is `Object`.

```
scala> Foo.getClass.getMethod("hashCode").invoke(Foo)
res13: Object = 1696677850
```

However, when I run the same program in Java...

```
    Object o = this.getClass().getMethod("hashCode").invoke
                                                    (new HashCode(), new Object[] {});
    System.out.println("o.getClass(): " + o.getClass());
    System.out.println("o: " + o);
```

I see a type of `Integer`:

```
>javac HashCode.java && java -cp . HashCode
o.getClass(): class java.lang.Integer
o: 1588658576
```

Why is Scala showing an `Object` type?

Comment: Because you compare different things? The first time you look at the result of invoke (which is also Object in your Java example) and the second time you look at its class object.

Comment: I'd say it is because the REPL displays the static type, while in your Java code, `o.getClass()` prints the dynamic class. For example, try in REPL:  
`scala> def foo: Any = 5`  
`foo: Any`  
`scala> foo`  
`res0: Any = 5`

Comment: Thanks `sschaef` and `Kulu`. Care to post for credit?